# Unable to read custom logs in promtail

Tags: kubernetes, grafana-loki, promtail

I am new to promtail and struggling to understand location from where it picks logs from each pod. I installed loki stack with promtail below are my default scrape_config

```
scrape_configs:
  # See also https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/master/production/ksonnet/promtail/scrape_config.libsonnet for reference
  - job_name: kubernetes-pods
    pipeline_stages:
      - cri: {}
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels:
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_controller_name
        regex: ([0-9a-z-.]+?)(-[0-9a-f]{8,10})?
        action: replace
        target_label: __tmp_controller_name
      - source_labels:
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app_kubernetes_io_name
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app
          - __tmp_controller_name
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
        regex: ^;*([^;]+)(;.*)?$
        action: replace
        target_label: app
      - source_labels:
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app_kubernetes_io_instance
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_release
        regex: ^;*([^;]+)(;.*)?$
        action: replace
        target_label: instance
      - source_labels:
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app_kubernetes_io_component
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_component
        regex: ^;*([^;]+)(;.*)?$
        action: replace
        target_label: component
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
        target_label: node_name
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - action: replace
        replacement: $1
        separator: /
        source_labels:
        - namespace
        - app
        target_label: job
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
        target_label: pod
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name
        target_label: container
      - action: replace
        replacement: /var/log/pods/*$1/*.log
        separator: /
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_uid
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name
        target_label: __path__
      - action: replace
        regex: true/(.*)
        replacement: /var/log/pods/*$1/*.log
        separator: /
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotationpresent_kubernetes_io_config_hash
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_kubernetes_io_config_hash
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name
        target_label: __path__
```

1- I want loki/promtail to pick some other log files but I am not sure on which location should I put these logs so that it is picked up by loki/promtails. I tried following paths but it did work

```
/app/logs
/var/log/containers
/var/log/pods
/var/log
/app
```

Look forward to replies. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am still struggling with issue, It would be great if some could share thoughts on this

Comment: did you fixed his issue?